aws iot rule: filtering based on dynamodb items
I like to apply filters on AWS IoT Rules based on items/attributes in dynamo db. For e.g. now I have a working AWS IoT Rule (below) which triggers when dynamodb has matching item (row) for the publishing device.
SELECT * FROM 'status/+' WHERE get_dynamodb('Devices', 'ID', clientid(), 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/dynamoget').environment = 'dev' 

I like to have an additional AWS IoT Rule which triggers when dynamodb does not return any item, i.e when get_dynamodb() returns nothing.  I tried below, but failed. If we enable logs in IoT Core Settings page, then we get below error messages in  CloudWatch under log group AWSIoTLogsV2.
SELECT * FROM 'status/+' WHERE isNull(get_dynamodb('Devices', 'ID', clientid(), 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/dynamoget'))


'Function 'GetDynamodb' failed to execute for rule
'Status_p6rVkoqr7svd'. Not able to retrieve and/or parse the
requested item from dynamo. ErrorMessage: '


It appears we can handle this scenario with aws_lambda() function. But that will need me to write an extra lambda function for a scenario  which seems to be achievable with SQL rule. I like to avoid writing extra lambda function.

Of lesser importance: adding background for alternate suggestions, I have many test and few dev devices connected to same aws iot core. I want to execute different iot rules for test and dev devices. So I created a dynamodb table with just dev devices item as they are few. Now the first rule for dev devices is working correctly. But I am unable to execute a rule for test devices which are missing in dynamo table. Hence the request for filter which is applicable when dynamodb does not have entries for test devices
